# Left align equation description

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

I have a short description for each of my equations. I want to have them flushleft (similar to the equation numbers which are flushright). How can I do that?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\text{this is my first equation: } z = x
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\text{this is my second equation: } z = x+y
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

And my desired output is like this:
[image]

Comment: Don't. Your readers will be grateful. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regular `align` with some macro-involvement would obtain the desired result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\newcommand{\alignmath}[2]{\makebox[0pt][#1]{$\displaystyle#2$}}
\newcommand{\lmath}[1]{\alignmath{l}{#1}}
\newcommand{\rmath}[1]{\alignmath{r}{#1}}
\newcommand{\cmath}[1]{\alignmath{c}{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  & \text{this is my first equation:}  & \cmath{z=x}   & \\
  & \text{this is my second equation:} & \cmath{z=x+y} & \\
  & \text{this is my third equation:} & \lmath{z=x+y}  & \\
  & \text{this is my fourth equation:} & \rmath{z=x+y} & \\
  & \text{this is my last equation:} & z &= x+y
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

`\cmath` inserts a zero-width box that is `c`entred. The advantage here is that you maintain the `align`-like vertical spacing.

I've added `\lmath` and `\rmath` for completeness, since `\makebox` allows for `l`eft- and `r`ight-aligned boxes. Also, the vertical rule indicates the horizontal alignment with respect to the default `align` - also supported in the above syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The following example uses environment `tabular*` to simulate the equations and to achieve the alignment requests:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\noindent A\hfill Z

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{%
  @{}l% description
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}%
  >{$\displaystyle}c<{$}% simulate displayed equation
  >{\refstepcounter{equation}\thetag\theequation}r@{}% equation number
}
this is my first equation:& z = x &\\
this is my second equation:& z = x + y &\\
\end{tabular*}
\end{center}

\noindent A\hfill Z
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]